# Получение массива из Promise {<pending>}

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

пытаюсь получить данные из **json** файла:

```
const getData = async () => {
const data = await fetch('db.json');

if (data.ok) {
  return data.json();
} else {
  throw new Error(`Данные не были получены, ошибка ${data.status} ${data.statusText}`);
}
};
```

Теперь когда хочу передать или просто увидеть массив через консоль, вот так:

```
const render = getData();
console.log(render);
```

То пишет мне :

```
Promise {<pending>}
 __proto__: Promise
 [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
 [[PromiseResult]]: Array(24)
```

Как этот массив **Array(24)** передать в переменную?
или обработать фильтром например.

Comment: Обычно в вашем случае отсылают сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/ Если что-то будет неясно и захотите разобраться в теме асинхронности основательно, стоит прочитать этот раздел: https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что `async` функции всегда возвращают экземпляр `Promise`.
Поэтому, либо используем `await` (если вызывающий код сам находится в `async` функции... или вне функций, если среда выполнения JS позволяет глобальный `await`):

```
try {
  const render = await getData();
  console.log(render);
  /* .... */
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

, либо помещаем обработку результата промиса в коллбэк метода `then`:

```
getData().then(render => {
  console.log(render);
  /* .... */
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: при первом варианте выдает ошибку - Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules.

Comment: Через then можно будет получить сам массив?

Comment: @ThekingArthur, если промис возвращаемый функцией `getData` резовит этот "сам массив" - то да, можно. Результат промиса передается в `then` аргументом (см. второй отрывок кода в ответе). А ошибка тебе заявляет, что `await` поддерживается только в `async` функциях и на верхнем уровне js-модулей (об этом тоже упоминается в начале ответа).

Comment: у меня выходит [[PromiseResult]]: undefined

Comment: Нужно ещё сделать `return await data.json();`  вроде бы

Comment: @ThekingArthur, добавь вывод ошибок в коллбэке метода `catch` (я дописал примеры ответа).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, можно (и иногда нужно), но в данном случае это совсем не обязательно (добавление `await` в выражение `return`'а, тут ничего не изменит: функция и так возвращает промис, так почему бы ей не возвращать тот промис который возвращается выражением `data.json()`...).